# Where is Screen Space Reflections in Blender 3.4?

Tags: rendering, materials

I'm following a tutorial for Blender that instructs me to check the Screen Space Reflections box. I cannot find this option anywhere - I believe the tutorial is probably working with an earlier version. Can anyone please help? Thanks!

Comment: Hello and welcome, firts, yo need to be sure that you are using EEVEE render engine inside the render properties, then you will see the option also inside render properties

Comment: Thank you so much! That was FAST! :) Much appreciated!